# How do I re-position a UIImageView in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, frame

I have a cellForRowAtIndexPath method that uses a switch to build cells like so:

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Usar mi ubicacion actual.jpg"];
            [cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, cell.imageView.image.size.width, cell.imageView.image.size.height)];
            break;
```

but its not working.  I changed it to this:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];


    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            self.locationButtonImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Usar mi ubicacion actual.jpg"];
            //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Usar mi ubicacion actual.jpg"];
            break;
```

The cell loads without the button image.  If I tap the cell, the toggle works and displays the selected button image and from then on it keeps toggling.  So it may be an issue of loading too late, right?

Comment: This would only work for the first cell.

Comment: Check whether image name is proper and your imageview is displaying the image else , it will not get the size proper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> UITableViewCell default style can't be overridden by position.

You need to customize the cell and add your own `imageView` to its `contentView` or subclass using xib file and add your `imageView` to it

Comment: ok thx, now I was originally using cellForRowAtIndexPath: but now i have a static cell with the uiimageview in it. The cell must have a button image that is toggle-able.  I have the logic already because i had it designed but now that ill eliminate the cellForRowAtIndexPath: how do I set the cell.imageView.image to my image?

Comment: you don't eliminate `cellFoRow` method.. without it tableView won't work